# How to configure Real-time developer notifications to use my back-end (https endpoint)?

Tags: android, google-api, google-play-services, in-app-billing, google-cloud-pubsub

I need to implement `Real-time developer notifications` in my backend server to be aware of any purchase modifications made by my users (pause account, renew subscriptions, etc.). My backend Server is made in `Delphi` and there are no ready-made libraries for Delphi, however, I can make an HTTPS endpoint to receive the notifications.

**How can I set up the Real-time developer notifications to use my HTTPS endpoint?**

Comment: Hello! I've made some research and there is already similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51927191/firebase-cloud-functions-to-android-application-notifications additionally I'll encourage you to check the official documentations: [1](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#rest), [2](https://developers.google.com/android/management/notifications) Let me know it if fits your needs.

Comment: @Ines thanks unfortunatly it's not help me :( I still can't find a way to set my https endpoint (don't even know where to set it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use an HTTPS endpoint to receive notifications, you'd want to set up a [push subscription](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push) in Cloud Pub/Sub on the topic you tie to the real-time developer notifications. First you'd [create a topic in Cloud Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/quickstart-console#create_a_topic). For example, you could do this using the `gcloud` command-line tool:

```
gcloud pubsub topics create developer-notifications
```

Next, you'd want to [create a push subscription](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/admin#creating_subscriptions) on that topic that points to your HTTPS endpoint. For example, you could do this from the `gcloud` command-line tool:

```
gcloud pubsub subscriptions create developer-notifications-sub \
    --topic developer-notifications \
    --push-endpoint=https://www.example.com/developer-notifications
```

Finally, you'd want to set up [real-time developer notifications](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/getting-ready#configure-rtdn) to publish to the Cloud Pub/Sub topic you created in the first step.

Once all of these steps are complete, your endpoint should receive the developer notifications via Cloud Pub/Sub.

Comment: Is RTDN free of cost or is there any pricing ?